# OpenGL ES Highlighting Algorithm for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am trying to do a highlighting action on the iPhone.  I can draw lines an such with the finger but now I want to be able to highlight over that.  Any algorithms out there you can point me to that does that?  Using OpenGL ES off course.

Thanks

Comment: Not really algorithm related.  removed the tag.

Comment: perhaps, if shading gives you the highlighting effect. Does it do that?  I want to be able to take a yellow highlighter and highlight over the text with it on touchBegan, touchMoved, and touchEnd.  What I need is the OpenGL code to give me the highlighting effect.

Answer (score 0):

This should produce a pink highlight around your geometry:

```
render_model();
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glLineWidth(2);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
render_model_using_GL_LINES();
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it with two changes:
1) changed glColor3f to glColor4f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f) because I am using OpenGL ES.
2) can't find render_model() and render_model_using_GL_LINES() equivalent on iPhone so I commented them out.  However, now I just can draw a pink stroke over everything, it does not highlight.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are u sure render_model() and render_model_using_GL_LINES() are valid function calls?  can't find them on the web

Comment: @Erika: render_model() and render_model_using_GL_LINES() are just shorthand for whatever code you have to render the geometry you want highlighted.